# Android JsonArrayRequest GET method is populating my ArrayList asyncronously

Tags: java, android, json, request

I'm trying to fetch Zones from my database in android studio. I have checked the API using `Postman`, so my `get_zones` API works just fine. However, in Android, I'm calling this method in  `onCreateView()` since this is a fragment. And in some mysterious way, the output would be like:
`1,12,123,1234,12345,123456...`
Instead of:
`1,2,3,4,5,6`
I have checked similar situations. A suggestion was like creating an interface named VolleyCallBack with a method `onSuccess()`. In method `onResponse()` everytime i create a zone with Jsonobject's parameters and add it to zoneList, I call `callback.onSuccess()` which i override it later in method call. Yet the result is as I've metioned.
For example in `onCreateView` method, after calling `fetchZones()` i check if `zoneList` is empty or not. And it is empty. However, my response is just fine.
In short, i want to obtain a `zoneList` that is populated by  jsonarrayrequest's response and i want to be able to manipulate items in this `zoneList` actively. Here is my code:

public class DashboardFragment extends Fragment {

```
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";


private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

View view;
LinearLayout layout;
RequestQueue queue;
private List<Zone> zoneList = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Device> deviceList = new ArrayList<>();

public DashboardFragment() {
}


public static DashboardFragment newInstance(String param1) {
    DashboardFragment fragment = new DashboardFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard,container,false);

    layout=(LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.linear);

    fetchZones(new VolleyCallBack() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
        }
    });
    fetchDevices(new VolleyCallBack() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
        }
    });
   

    return view;
}

public void fetchZones(final VolleyCallBack callback){
    String url = "http://10.0.2.2:80/api/index.php?action=get_zones";

    queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            System.out.println(response);
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    Zone zone = new Zone(response.getJSONObject(i).getInt("id"), response.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"),
                            response.getJSONObject(i).getString("location"), response.getJSONObject(i).getString("purpose"));
                    addTextView(zone);
                    zoneList.add(zone);
                    callback.onSuccess();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });

    queue.add(req);
}
public void fetchDevices(final VolleyCallBack callBack){
    String url = "http://10.0.2.2:80/api/index.php?action=get_devices";

    queue= Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            System.out.println(response);
            for(int i=0;i<response.length();i++){
                try{
                    Device device= new Device(response.getJSONObject(i).getInt("id"),response.getJSONObject(i).getString("name")
                            ,response.getJSONObject(i).getString("type_id"),response.getJSONObject(i).getString("zone_id"));
                    System.out.println(device);
                    deviceList.add(device);
                    callBack.onSuccess();
                }catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    queue.add(req);
}

private void addTextView(final Zone zone) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(DashboardFragment.this.getActivity());
    textView.setId(zone.getId());
    textView.setText(zone.getName());
    textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    textView.setTextSize(25);
    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplication(), ZoneContentsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("zoneId",Integer.toString(zone.getId()));
            intent.putExtra("zoneList_size",zoneList.size());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    layout.addView(textView);

}
```

}

This is my first time posting a question here, sorry about the mess.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with a simple if statement! I declared a local int with name responseLength. Then i set it to be equal to the length of response. In my onSuccess() method, I did everything in this following if statement:

```
if (zoneList.size()== ResponseLenght){
//Everything is in there
}
```